# SQL foreign key constraint datetime to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables with `datetime2` column in each and I want to create a foreign key constraint that will take only the date part as a foreign key constraint.

Is there a way to do it? if not what is my alternatives (beside create 2 columns of `date` types in each table)?

```
ALTER TABLE TableA
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TableA_TableB
FOREIGN KEY (DateTime2_TableA) REFERENCES TableB(DateTime2_TableB);
```

Comment: I don't think you have a better alternative than splitting the `datetime2` columns to `date` and `time` columns in both tables.

Comment: Do you need a constraint that works even when deleting rows from TableB? If you don't you can use a check constraint, otherwise I think you will have to add the date columns

Comment: You could add persisted computed column to your table and use it in a foreign key constraint: ALTER TABLE TableA ADD d  AS CONVERT(date, DateTime2_TableA) PERSISTED